# Pass command to cygwin shell script

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin

I can't get the following to work:

**c:\cygwin64\bin\bash -c /cygdrive/c/myscript.sh myargument**

Specifically, myscript.sh is NOT getting "myargument" passed in as $1.

The script works exactly as I want it to if I hard-code "myargument" inside the script.

It's been 5 years since I have done any shell scripting and rust has accumulated!

Comment: `... -c "script arg"`. otherwise `myargument` will be treated as an argument to the bash call, not the script.

Comment: Marc, I use quotes like you showed and that worked. Is there any advantage to -c with quotes compared to just leaving out the -c?

Answer (score 2):

The option -c is not used with scripts
Try this instead:

```
c:\cygwin64\bin\bash /cygdrive/c/myscript.sh myargument
```